# How set alias for FROM ? in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So i've been trying to figure how to set alias for ->from() in eloquent for a while... and i don't think it exist ?

Is this only achievable in query builder ? Or am i missing something

Comment: How do you mean set alias for `from`, you mean you want to use a different table name on the same model?

Comment: Why do you want to alias it?

Comment: @RossWilson there is a part in my query where i compare the table against a slightly different query of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change your column name.
You can do like this.

```
\DB::table('table_name')
        ->select('name as firstname')
        ->get();
```

if you want to change your table name.
You can do like this.

```
\DB::table('table_name as t1')
        ->select('name as firstname')
        ->get();
```

in **eloquent** you can't change table name but you can change column name like this.

```
User::select('name as firstname')
        ->get();
```

Comment: is this answer is useful for you?

Comment: reason why im determine it to be eloquent is because i want to apply a scope to my query ... however as you show above it seems like i can't and have limited choices...  so thanks anyways :P  . Probably will just apply the scope query manually on the query builder.